# Should I be Using a Thread?

Tags: multithreading, loops

I made a console application which makes the mouse click in the middle of the screen every two minutes. It has a `while True` loop in it which is meant to keep going for relatively long periods of time (until the application is closed). Should this really long loop be put in a thread? It seems to work as it is, but I'm not sure about how good it is not to use a thread.

Comment: It's already in a thread. Do you mean it's own dedicated thread?

Comment: I meant a dedicated thread

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does your application need to do anything else?

Does it need to respond to commands sent to the console while it does it's thing?

Does it need to also check files or other resources?

You should use threads only if you need multiple things done concurrently.  If your app only does one thing then the main thread should be good enough.

That said, even if you do have multiple things that needs be done, you might not need threads either, you can just as easily perform each task sequentially and start back at the first one in a loop.  There are pros and cons to each approach but neither is bad per se.

Threading, though very powerfull, adds a lot of complexity.  If you don't need it, don't do it.

Comment: While good questions to ask, this gives people the wrong impression. OP absolutely should be using a background thread to do this work. There's no reason to tie up the CPU for minutes on end with a busy loop.  (Actually, a Threading.Timer is probably most appropriate for the use case.)

Comment: @RubberDuck OP said, "It seems to work as it is."  Nobody ever needs to change code that works.  Newtopian is asking, does it _really_ work (i.e., does it do everything that OP imagined and hoped for)? or is there something _else_ that OP wants it to do, but hasn't figured out the best way.

Comment: @jameslarge letting a busy loop eat up the CPU is irresponsible at best.

Comment: @RubberDuck, that would be true in any desktop, server, or mobile-phone environment, but I don't see how you got from "It has a while True loop in it" to "[it ties] up the CPU for minutes on end."  Not every `while(true)` loop is a busy-wait loop.

Comment: You assume that the remainder of the 2 minutes the OP is busy waiting for the time to have elapsed.  If however he simply used a sleep for 2 minutes the loop is not so "busy" anymore.  A bad or misbehaving program will not electromagically be made better by putting it in a thread.

Comment: @RubberDuck I can't say whether the infinite loop is eating CPU irresponsibly without understanding what mechanism is used to wait the 2 minutes. If it is calling Thread.sleep I would be OK with that.

Comment: In that case @ThomasCarlisle, you're needlessly tying up a thread that doesn't need to be tied up. This should, objectively, be implemented with a Timer.

Comment: @RubberDuck, there is nothing in the OP that says the app needs to do any other task. If it does, I'd agree a separate thread is a good choice. In my mind, the key point is making sure that the mechanism being used to wait the 2 minutes is not tying up the CPU.

Comment: Indeed, a timer would do nicely but if that is all my app does I would not even bother with it and go for the simpler loop+sleep solution.  The timer does have some subtle side effects one needs to be aware of, for example, if the task to be done takes longer than the period allotted to the timer.  This situation could potentially lead to slow leaks or concurrency problems that can be hard to debug.  I doubt this would arise in this case though I have seen UI interactions like this behave in some very unpredictable ways.  Never underestimate the power of a trivial solution.

Answer (score 1):

Not because it makes it happen in its own thread(even though it does) -- but you should really be using a built in timer and just letting it call the function delegate instead of looping and checking the time yourself.

Comment: Perhaps I could use a recursive function which calls itself every 2 minutes.

Comment: I recommend against this b/c you'll end up making the call stack supremely high and variables won't be deallocated.   What exactly are you doing?  What language?   We can tell you how to set up a timer if you don't know how?  Maybe I'm assuming too much about where you're getting stuck?

Comment: I'm using Python for this

Comment: So you want to do something like:

`import threading
  
def click_mouse_in_middle():
 <code to click in here>
 
 
def start_clicking_mouse(seconds):
 threading.Timer(seconds,click_mouse_in_middle).start()`

Comment: good luck.  I need to learn markdown lol.